# R Shiny: Accessing reactive elements in nested shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I have a nested set of shiny modules, where main UI takes a textInput() and calls an add/remove button module, which in turn calls a module called "first", which takes the textInput() value and prepends the choices in a selectInput() box consisting of "a", "b", "c", "d" as those choices.  For example, if user types in "1" (default), the selectInput() box called by the add/remove button module would show choices as "1a", "1b", "qc", and "1d".  I want to pass to the main server logic the result of the selectInput() box in "first" module.  So I am passing the result of selectInput() as a return of "first" module, then assign it as reactive value in addRmBtn() module, and I would like to pass both that value and the param$btn value, which is the (net) number of times the add button was clicked.  I am getting an error in the addRmBtnServer() module because I am not properly assigning the return of "first" module to reactive element in addRmBtnServer().  Code is below.  Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "first")) }

firstServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {
    ns = session$ns

    output$first <- renderUI({
        selectInput(ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0(isolate(a()), letters[1:4]))
    })

    return(reactive({ paste0(input$select) }))
}

removeFirstUI <- function(id) {
    removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "first")))
}

addRmBtnUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    tags$div(
    actionButton(inputId = ns('insertParamBtn'), label = "Add"),
    actionButton(ns('removeParamBtn'), label = "Remove"),
    hr(),
    tags$div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

addRmBtnServer <- function(input, output, session, moduleToReplicate, ...) {
    ns = session$ns

    params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)

    observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
        params$btn <- params$btn + 1

       returnA <-  callModule(moduleToReplicate$server, id = params$btn, ...)
        insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = moduleToReplicate$ui(ns(params$btn))
    )
    })

    observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
        moduleToReplicate$remover(ns(params$btn))
        params$btn <- params$btn - 1
    })

    return(reactive({ c(returnA(), params$btn) }))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  addRmBtnUI("addRm"),
  textInput("a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px'),
    verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    a <- reactive({ input$a })
    comp <- callModule(
    addRmBtnServer, id = "addRm",
    moduleToReplicate = list(
      ui = firstUI,
      server = firstServer,
      remover = removeFirstUI
    ),
    a = a
  )
    output$output <- renderText({ paste("a = ", a(), "comp = ", comp()) })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The problem is you assign `returnA` inside the `observeEvent` scope, so it is not accessible in `addRmBtnServer `. You can use `params$returnA <-  callModule(moduleToReplicate$server,...)` instead. That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to give more minimalistic example codes in the future, if possible. Questions posted on SO are meant to help future visitors as well. If they have to go through 80-ish lines of code, that isn't very helpful for them. Also it makes your questions much harder to answer.

Anyways, I implemented the functionality you are after. The `addRmButtonServer` now returns a list of choices as well as the button value. All the values are stored in the `param` variable inside the `addRmButtonServer` scope. The values can be accessed in the main `server` scope as `returnValue$a[[firstUI_index]]()`. See `output$text`.

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) { uiOutput(NS(id, "first")) }

firstServer <- function(input, output, session, a) {
  ns = session$ns

  output$first <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("select"), h4("Select"), paste0(isolate(a()), letters[1:4]))
  })

  return(reactive({ paste0(input$select) }))
}

removeFirstUI <- function(id) {
  removeUI(selector = paste0('#', NS(id, "first")))
}

addRmBtnUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tags$div(
    actionButton(inputId = ns('insertParamBtn'), label = "Add"),
    actionButton(ns('removeParamBtn'), label = "Remove"),
    hr(),
    tags$div(id = ns('placeholder'))
  )
}

addRmBtnServer <- function(input, output, session, moduleToReplicate, ...) {
  ns = session$ns

  params <- reactiveValues(btn = 0, a = list())

  observeEvent(input$insertParamBtn, {
    params$btn <- params$btn + 1

    params$a[[params$btn]] <- callModule(moduleToReplicate$server, id = params$btn, ...)
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns('placeholder')),
      ui = moduleToReplicate$ui(ns(params$btn))
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$removeParamBtn, {
    moduleToReplicate$remover(ns(params$btn))
    params$btn <- params$btn - 1
  })

  return(params)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  addRmBtnUI("addRm"),
  textInput("a", label = "a", value = 1, width = '150px'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  a <- reactive({ input$a })
  comp <- callModule(
    addRmBtnServer, id = "addRm",
    moduleToReplicate = list(
      ui = firstUI,
      server = firstServer,
      remover = removeFirstUI
    ),
    a = a
  )
  output$text <- renderText({ 
    if(comp$btn>0)
      paste(
        "a = ", comp$a[[comp$btn]](), 
        "comp = ", comp$btn
      ) 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect, this clears up my confusion.  I understand the need for making simpler examples, this was the simplest that I could think of which illustrates the functionality I need.  Thank you so much for your clear explanation, I now have enough understanding of shiny to properly build the modularized shiny apps that I need for our company.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. May I ask why you don't want accept this answer and two other answers I gave you previously?

Comment: Thought I did.  Will do now.